# Is it good to add a new field to an existing table?

Tags: magento2, database

I need to add a new field to a Magento table  **sales_order_item**  in order to complete a task. But I am not sure if it is a good idea to do so.

Will this cause the problem for upgrading to a newer version later, Since the **sales_order_item** table is Magento core table?

I'm using Magento 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its always recommended that we do **NOT** change any code or database structure of Magento's core functionality.
Magento comes with a highly flexible structure which allows to add new as well as update existing functionality without making any change to its core. Altering core tables may result in errors during upgrade or migration process.
I will suggest you not to change core tables. Instead you can create a new table with a reference to Magento's **sales_order_item** table and use **join** to get data.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate how exactly can I connect this new table with Magento's sales_order_item? I can easily create a new table with a custom module. But then I don't know how to connect this two table together.

Comment: You can add reference key to your custom table column which has reference to **sales_flat_order_item**'s `item_id` column.

Comment: Hmm, not sure that add new table for each new field will be better. Can it slow down query if we have to join for example 10 tables? I guess it will work slower.
Also what issue we can have on magento upgrade if we use unique field_names? (something like "myuniqcompany_fieldname")

Comment: You don't have to add a new table for each field, you can add a single custom table and can add as many as fields you want and then use join to get them all. @alex